# How do I query the clicked connection and any arguments of a QPushButton in PySide2/PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, maya, pyside2

Looking to query the function and arguments that my QPushButtons have once I've dragged a box around them.

so far my code for connecting controls:

```
def connect_ctrls(self):
    # connects the controls (buttons) to a respective function
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.howdy, 'herp'))
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.later)
```

The function each calls:

```
def howdy(self, *_):
    print('Hello')
    print(_)
    
def later(self, *_):
    print('Goodbye')
```

And the code for when I release the box I dragged across them:

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == qtc.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.rubberBand.hide()
        selected = []
        rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
        for child in self.findChildren(qtw.QPushButton):
            if rect.intersects(child.geometry()):
                selected.append(child)
        for sel in selected:
            sel.click()
            ### REVISE: get the function and arguments for each button the rubberBand intersected with
```

Sure I can "click" each button upon selection but I want to query the connected function and arguments of each button instead. Any ideas where that information can be queried? I'm not finding anything on doc.qt.io or google searches.

*Edit: I do not want to execute a button.clicked connection and query it from there, I want what would happen. What is clicking the button(s) connected to and what arguments would said button(s) send?

Comment: what do you mean by " I want to query the connected function and arguments of each button"

Comment: I want to get/query/return/pass into a pointer/variable, the function that a button.clicked signal is connected to, and any arguments it would pass.
in my code for the pushbutton: self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.howdy, 'herp'))
I just want to be able to query the "partial(self.howdy, 'herp')" part. It could be as a string, it could be as a tuple/list. Just looking to get that information.

Comment: pretty much I want the equivalent to cmds.button(self.pushButton, q = True, c = True)

Comment: You cannot query signal connections, and while getting them is not impossible, it's quite difficult, not always reliable, and **always** requires keeping a persistent reference to them, which is impossible if you directly use a `partial` as an argument and not a reference to it; see [this partially related post](//stackoverflow.com/q/2755694). The real question, here, is: why do you need to do that?

Comment: I did come across that related post when I was looking, but as I'm not very proficient in PySide/PyQt, I could barely make head's or tail's of it. I'm making a picker for maya with the ability to use modifier keys for adding, toggliing, and removing from the current selection... but I also wanted the ability to click drag around buttons to select what they were made for selecting (having the command to just trigger the .click in a for loop results in only the last object selected.